VBA - Search & Display : result doesn't take comment/URL into account
I've been working on a dynamic search bar in Excel, following this video, and it works fine.
=IF(I3="","No match",FILTER(Table1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I3,Table1[Sujet])),"No match"))
However, it doesn't display meta info from the cell (comment, URL...) meant to make the result a bit more interactive. In the attached image, looking for "machine" will display the cell that is containing such additional info, but no active Link, nor a Comment icon.

Is it an option I'm overlooking, or a limitation ?
I know even less about Excel and its formulas than VBA... The formula came from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4WbzvYwAUI but there's no comments, and the file provided isn't even complete !

It's a limitation.  FILTER will return the values from the cells and won't include comments, formatting or links.

Aw, shucks. Would there be a way to get those infos ?

You might be able to do something with the HYPERLINK and IMAGE functions.  IMAGE is a pretty new function so only available in 365 and as far as I know it will only pick up images from an URL and not network drives, etc.  Other than that you'd probably need VBA.

I've tried something, but Worksheet_Change doesn't work, probably for the same reason that it's limited by the Filter...
